# <Route>s match based on previous path when navigating using <Link>

Tags: hyperlink, routes, react-router, switch-statement, react-router-dom

When I navigate using a react-router `<Link>` to a page that has a `<Switch>` component on it with multiple `<Route>` s, the `<Route>` that ends up matching is one whose path I was previously on, rather than the current (new) path. It's as if the  executes before react-router is aware that the path has changed. This causes the wrong component to render. Am I doing something wrong?

react-router-dom version: 4.2.2

Example:

I have a Header component that looks like this (simplified):

```
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

export default (props) => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route
        path='/checkout'
        render={(match, location) => {
          console.log('path:', location.pathname)
          return <CheckoutHeader>
        }}
      />
      <Route
        path='/cart'
        render={(match, location) => {
          console.log('path:', location.pathname)
          return <NormalHeader>
        }}
      />
    </Switch>
  )
}
```

On my '/cart' page, I have this:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom

export default (props) => {
  return (
    <Link to='/checkout'>Go to checkout</Link>
  )
}
```

If I navigate using the URL bar to my /cart page, I see the Normal header and `path: /cart` is logged, which is correct.

But when I click the Link, the normal header remains, and `path: /cart` is logged again. I expect to see `path: /checkout` here, and the checkout header.

Refreshing the page fixes the problem, and replacing the React-Router link with a regular html link fixes it as well, but then of course we have to re-render the whole page and lose our redux store.